# Ninject: Switch Between InRequestScope and InSingletonScope

Tags: scope, ninject

I have separate Ninject modules for each of my application layers, defined in their own projects. I am trying to reuse the same modules in console applications, services and my web application. However, for a handful of the bindings I scope them differently depending on the type of the app: `InSingletonScope`, `InRequestScope`, etc. Right now, these bindings are ending up in my top-level modules because of the differences in scope. For instance, in my web application, the scope of the `DbContext` is set to `InRequestScope`. It is set to `InSingletonScope` in my console applications.

Eventually, I would like to break the direct dependency between my top-level project and the projects where the implementations reside. It would be nice to say, "find the binding for T and apply this scope to it." It doesn't look like this is supported. I was wondering if there was a way to update a binding's scope after-the-fact or decorate a Ninject module with a scope to use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the scope of an existing binding in Ninject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24613102/how-to-change-the-scope-of-an-existing-binding-in-ninject)